# How to use Chart.js in chrome extension v3

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chart.js, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to leverage Chart.js library to produce some charts in my Chrome extension. I am using manifest v3 version that does not allow cdn usage in any way possible. How can I use Chart.js in my Chrome extension please help me out. I had tried downloading its files so that I could include them directly in my extension but I cannot find the exact files I needed to do so. Please guide me so that I can use the library.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample of it.

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "chart.js sample",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "sandbox": {
    "pages": [
      "popup.html"
    ]
  },
  "content_security_policy": {
    "sandbox": "sandbox allow-scripts; script-src 'unsafe-inline' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net"
  }
}
```

popup.html

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div>
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
  
  <script>
    const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
  
    new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
          borderWidth: 1
        }]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```